# In nodeJs socket.io on method is unresolved in webstorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, npm

I am learning socket.io in node and i have installed the module using-

```
npm install socket.io --save
```

here is my code

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

[image]

> but webstorm is saying that 'on' is unresolved .. please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try -

```
var io = new require('socket.io')(http);
```

and make sure you are including this script on client side

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io();
</script>
```

Answer (score 16):

1. Open 'Settings' in WebStorm (Ctrl+Alt+S)
2. Go to 'Languages & Frameworks' → 'JavaScript' → 'Libraries'
3. Press 'Download'
4. Select the libriary 'socket.io'
5. Press 'Download and install'

That's all folks!

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Comment: Perfect! no more squigglies on all of my `namespace.on` statements.

Comment: It works also for PhpStorm

Answer (score 1):

I did not include this script on client side that is why

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io();
</script>
```