# Node.js: websocket and express server shows unresolved server Problem

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I am trying to install a new websocket server with an existing express server like this:

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

const server = http.createServer(app);

const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({server:server});

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    console.log('A new client Connected!');
    ws.send('Welcome New Client!');

    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);

        wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
            if (client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                client.send(message);
            }
        });

    });
});

//routing
const roomsRoute = require('./Implementierung/Ressourcen/rooms');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hear them');
});

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

First, I got a problem with this line:

```
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({server:server});
```

I am not able to create a new WebSocket Server this way.

[image]

At second:

```
if (client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                client.send(message);
            }
```

WebSocket.OPEN shows an error, maybe because of non-existing WebSocket?

Comment: The `OPEN` constant is available at the WebSocket client which is `ws` in your case so try `ws.OPEN`. Can you explain `I am not able to create a new WebSocket Server`? Do you get any error? If yes, can you show the full error stack?

Comment: When typing const wss = new WebSocket.Server({server:server}) Server is an unresolved type.

Comment: Ok, so that probably has nothing to do with your code but rather your code editor/linter/typescript etc. You don't get any error wher running the code, do you?

Comment: no, server is running. I changed WebSocket.OPEN to ws.OPEN, this works now. But there's no message for the websocket server on the terminal

Comment: If you see the *"unresolved type"* message in your editor can you show the screenshot?

Comment: i added the screenshot to my question above

Comment: Ok that is just warning from WebStorm editor. It doesn't mean there's anything wrong with your code. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39930479/in-nodejs-socket-io-on-method-is-unresolved-in-webstorm/54357222 look at the top answer not the accepted one.

Comment: found these three options: socket.io-file, socket.io-p2p and socket.io-users. Which one of these is the right one?

Comment: Actually none of them. Since you use `ws` package you need to find something for that. I'm not familiar with WebStorm so not sure.

Comment: i've still not found a solution. i am working with intellij ultimate and node.js

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html and add a `ws` library

Comment: Ok. Feeling lost :-)  The only library I found in external Libraries for node.js to download is express-ws. But I thought ws is already installed and implemented with require 'ws'? Followed the instruction from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#external-https-server and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wV-fDdHhGqs&t=387s

Comment: How are you testing your server code? Include the client side code that you are using to connect to the server.

Comment: the express server is running without problems. The problem is to create a websocket server with the existing express server. I found this article now https://medium.com/factory-mind/websocket-node-js-express-step-by-step-using-typescript-725114ad5fe4. This example uses express-ws as a library. Maybe this is the reason? I did this: "npm install ws"

Comment: Still no solution. Found another code sample but running with atom and node js https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5BQKgP9x7o without problems. I work with intellij and node.js. Maybe intellij is the problem. But how to solve?

Comment: What you need is to install Typescript definitions for `ws` package to intellij as explained in the link i provided above. Try this https://resources.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2021.3/ws_js_libs_download_ts_definitions_intention_action.png but select `ws` instead of express in your code and it should offer you in the context menu to install missing typescript definition. In the other hand if you don't care about the additional info the intellij offers you can safely ignore the warning, it's not gonna affect your code.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript was the solution! Thanks all for help